# What is best practice on show temporary object and update it with original object in ios?

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject, nsobject, temporary-objects

Asking this question is just to know the right way to update the existing contents after a user adds new content.

Here is the scenario:

- Consider my app is like notes app, which can save the note in my server using API
- The user tries to add new note by tapping create button. Then he hits the "*Save*" icon to save the typed note
- Now, I need to call API (Say, *addNotes* API) to store the typed note in my server
- I need to also resign the "*Create Note*" page in my app immediately
- When the user see the notes list page, he will immediately expect the typed note
- But as per theory, to update the notes list view, I need the API response
- In practical, the resigning of "*Create Note*" page happens first. Because sending API, getting response, calling delegates, parsing content, creating responsible views/cells for the new item will take more time that resigning a view controller
- Here comes the problem. For a smooth experience, most of us shows temporary object (which is stored locally) when the "*Create Note*" page resigns. After getting the API response, we will update the temporary object with original object

Consider I use `NSManagedObject` instead of just string like notes app. So I need to create a temporary object and should gave it to the list view from "*Create*" view.

**Questions:**

- Should I create a temporary `NSManagedObject`? Or is it enough to create just a `NSObject` same like `NSManagedObject`?
- With `NSManagedObject`/`NSObject`, I can show a temporary data in list view. After I get the API response, should I delete the temporary object and add the original object or should I update the temporary object? (In this case, I think that I need to create the temporary `NSManagedObject` object)

This may be a basic question, but eager to know the best practice from experts.

Thanks

Comment: I would probably have a look at this : http://blog.denivip.ru/index.php/2014/04/data-syncing-in-core-data-based-ios-apps/?lang=en and http://inessential.com/vespersyncdiary. Those are quite good articles on how to sync between coredata and an API.